# Searching for a string in an array without strcmp

Tags: arrays, c, string, search

I have a struct in this form:

```
typedef struct student{
    double student_no;
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    double phone_no;
    char mail[50];
};
struct student person[100];

printf("Student's mail address: ");
scanf("%s", person[i].mail); //i use codeblocks and it works without the sign &
```

First I create an array of mails. Then I get a mail for user, then check if it is in my array that I created in the first place. I have to do it without `strcmp()`, and that's where I get stuck. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
char *e1, *e2;
int comp;

typedef struct info{
    char email[50];
};
struct info mailaddress[0];

printf("Enter the mail address to search: ");
scanf("%s", mailaddress[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < u; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < u; j++) {
        e1 = person[i].mail;
        e2 = mailaddress[j].email;
        comp = 0;

        while (*e1 && *e2) {
            if (*e1 != *e2) {
                comp = *e1 - *e2;
                break;
            }

            ++e1;
            ++e2;
        }

        if (comp == 0)
            printf("%s\t  %s  %15.lf    %15.lf      %s\n",
                    person[i].name,
                    person[i].surname,
                    person[i].student_no,
                    person[i].phone_no,
                    person[i].mail);
    }
}
```

Comment: This declaration struct info mailaddress[0]; is invalid You may not declare an array with zero elements.

Comment: "i have to do it without strcmp()" Learn how `strcmp` works, then write your own version.

Comment: The `while(*e1 && *e2)` should use `||` instead of `&&` so that it works when the strings are not the same length. If the strings are identical up to the length of the shortest string, then the longer string will compare greater than the short string. (This assumes all the characters have non-negative values.)

Comment: I would like to highlight 1.8e9's comment.  I recommend this strategy: Step 1.  Write your program, using `strcmp`.  (Yes, I know, you're not allowed to, but bear with me.) Debug your program thoroughly, make sure it's working correctly in all cases.  Step 2. Write your own version of `strcmp`, perhaps called `my_strcmp`.  It should be just like the standard version, accepting two `const char *` arguments, and returning an `int`. Step 3. (optional) Write a separate little program to test your `my_strcmp` thoroughly.  Step 4. Make the simple change to step 1's program to use `my_strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NO_MAX       20
#define NAME_MAX     20
#define SURNAME_MAX  20
#define PHONE_NO_MAX 20
#define MAIL_NO_MAX  50

struct student{
    char    student_no[NO_MAX + 1];
    char    name[NAME_MAX + 1];
    char    surname[SURNAME_MAX + 1];
    char    phone_no[PHONE_NO_MAX + 1];
    char    mail[MAIL_NO_MAX + 1];
    struct student *ptr_next;
 };

struct student *ptr_head = NULL;
struct student *ptr_position;


void enter_item(char *ptr_label, char *ptr_result, int max){

    // enter item until pressed enter to finished
    char tmp[256];
    do {
        printf("%s: ", ptr_label);
        gets(tmp);
    } while((strlen(tmp) > max));
    strcpy(ptr_result, tmp);
}

void enter_list(void) {
    char more;
    struct student *ptr_new;
    do{
        // order dynamic memory
        ptr_new = (struct student *) malloc(sizeof(struct student));
        if(ptr_new) {
            // enter item
            enter_item("student_no", ptr_new->student_no, NO_MAX);
            enter_item("name",       ptr_new->name, NAME_MAX);
            enter_item("surename",   ptr_new->surname, SURNAME_MAX);
            enter_item("phone_no",   ptr_new->phone_no, PHONE_NO_MAX);
            enter_item("mail",       ptr_new->mail, MAIL_NO_MAX);

            // next item
            ptr_new-> ptr_next = ptr_head;
            ptr_head = ptr_new;

            // enter item again or not
            printf("- again(Y/N)? -");
            do{
               more = toupper(getch());
            } while(!(more=='Y' || more=='N'));
            printf(" %c\n\n", more);
        }
        else {
            printf("Memory isn't enough!\n");
            break;
        }
    } while(more == 'Y');
}


void search_mail() {
    // enter mail
    struct student *ptr_search;

    ptr_search = (struct student *) malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    enter_item("mail searching",       ptr_search->mail, MAIL_NO_MAX);
    char *mail = ptr_search->mail;

    // searching mail
    ptr_position = ptr_head;
    while(ptr_position) {
        if(strcmp(mail, ptr_position->mail) != 0) {
            ptr_position = ptr_position-> ptr_next;
        }
        else {
            printf("Email is found\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Email isn't found!\n");
}

int main()
{
    enter_list();
    search_mail();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: see here to understand how linked lists work: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

```
bool streq(char *a, char *b)
{
    while (*a && *b && *a != *b)
        a++, b++;

    return !*a && !*b;
}
```